# Select entire table contents and insert into another table with the same column names

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables that have the same column names. Is there a way of getting the contents from one table and inserting it into another. I could export it into a sreadsheet then import it into the other table but would prefer to quickly use mysql. My experience with php and mysql is mainly selecting and inserting from one table.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html):

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2
```

Note that this will only work if the tables are defined with columns in the same order; otherwise one will have to explicitly name the columns in one (or both) of the `INSERT` and `SELECT` parts of the command:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (colA, colB, colC) SELECT colA, colB, colC FROM table2
```